# gstreamer-1.0's ximagesrc vsync

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, vsync

I am using `gstreamer-1.0` with `ximagesrc` for capturing the screen of my Linux box...

Unfortunately I see some "tearing" on the captured images, and I guess it is due to the lack of v-sync while grabbing the desktop...

Is v-sync supported somehow by `ximagesrc`? Does it depend on system configuration and/or driver? Looking at `ximagesrc` [documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-ximagesrc.html) I can't find any useful details about that... but maybe there is some "black magic" for making this working... :)

Comment: Is that with the nvidia closed source driver?

Comment: No, I am using an embedded system based on Intel J1900 processor, so we are speaking about the HD Integrated Graphics and the correspondent driver

Comment: Then maybe this may help: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37686

Comment: Thanks @FlorianZwoch: I am going to take a look